# Focus Jumps to Address

Tags: asp.net

I am working on an ASP.NET 2.0 (VB) web application. I am having trouble controlling tab behavior.

TabIndex is set throughout the form and tabs as expected.

But,after making a change in a textbox and hitting Tab or Enter, the focus jumps to the web address bar instead of the next field.

I have tried:

1.SetFocus on the text change event

2.Saving last field name in a hidden textbox and set focus to saved textbox name on Page Load if Post back

3.SetFocus on Pre_render

Still, focus jumps to browser address bar on tab or enter.

I think it may be losing the tab index on post-back.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you have AutoPostBack on a TextBox control with TabIndex assigned it could be a little complex to manipulate the Focus. [Check out this tutorial](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=253) which will show you a little trick to Shift Focus to the next control.

Good luck!